# How to limit the available Date ranges with the appsScript Datebox only Last one Month dates Should be available to select

Tags: google-apps-script

How to limit the available Date ranges with the appsScript Datebox only Last one Month dates Should be available to select eg : If Today is `25/08/2014` then **User can select date between the the range** `25/07 - 25/08`. i am using UI Service

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately not possible to select the available range of a dateBox nor to check date values using client handler in UiApp, you will have to use a server handler function to get that functionality.

Below is an example and the corresponding code.

*note that I didn't limit the highest date value but that will be easy to implement using one more condition on today's date in the handler function + adapting the Label warning message, I preferred keeping the example as readable as possible.*

[test online](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyUrTpuistt5mVY1voSknEqwxbcLSLBlta8ahP5xbhSlhG-1yI/exec)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var p = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','50px');
  var oneMonthAgo = new Date(new Date().getTime()-31*86400000);
  p.add(app.createLabel('Choose a date (later than '+Utilities.formatDate(oneMonthAgo,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'MMM  dd,  yyyy  ')+')'));
  var dateHandler = app.createServerHandler('checkTime').addCallbackElement(p);
  p.add(app.createDateBox().setName('date').setId('date').setValue(new Date()).addValueChangeHandler(dateHandler));
  var btnHandler = app.createServerHandler('checkTime').addCallbackElement(p);
  var btn = app.createButton('submit',btnHandler).setEnabled(false).setId('btn');
  p.add(btn);
  p.add(app.createLabel().setId('resp').setStyleAttribute('paddingTop','30px'));
  app.add(p);
  return app;
}

function checkTime(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var date = e.parameter.date;
  var oneMonthAgo = new Date().getTime()-31*86400000;
  if(date.getTime()<oneMonthAgo){
    app.getElementById('resp').setText('date must less than one month ago...');
    return app;
  }
  if(e.parameter.source =='date'){
    app.getElementById('resp').setText('date accepted with value '+date.toLocaleString());
    app.getElementById('btn').setEnabled(true);
  }else{
    app.getElementById('resp').setText('request accepted.. continue the current job');
    }
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.createDateBox()` try putting only the valid dates in a list box...

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var listBox = app.createListBox(false).setId('date').setName('date');
  var today = new Date();

  for ( var i=0; i < 29; i++ ) {
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() - i * 86400000), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
    listBox.addItem(date)
  }

  app.add(listBox);
  return app;
}
```